# javascript / NodeJS - Sending Data from nodejs app to html file using send and get

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, get

id like to build a sftp client app using nodejs. Currently i am able to receive lsEntries from the Server and print them to the Terminal.

```
    var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors);

var connSettings = {
  host: myserver,
  port: 22,
  username: myuser,
  password: passwd
};
var remotePathToList = '/';

var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function(){
  conn.sftp(function(err, sftp){
    if(err) throw err;

    sftp.readdir(remotePathToList, function(err, list){

      if(err) throw err;
      var contents = []
      contents = (list);

      for(var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++){
        console.log(contents[i].filename);
      }

      app.get('/data', function(req, res){
        res.send(contents);
      });
      app.listen(3000);

      //close connection
      conn.end();

    });

  });
}).connect(connSettings);
```

In order to receive the data in my frontend i have the folowing JQuery Code:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $.get('http://localhost:3000/data', {}, function(data){
        var myData = (data);
        console.log(myData.length);
      });
    });
  });
```

But i don't receive an answer. Sometimes i get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE after a very long time of waiting. Note that i'm using 'cors' to prevent the Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error. However, when i type localhost:3000 in my browser i get the data printed to the screen (JSON).
What is the correct way to access the lsEntry array from the frontend?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ah, i solved the problem. Using cors didn't work, but i found a solution, that allows cors with express:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
  Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

It replaces

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors);
```

and works. I don't know why the npm package didn't work, but i found the solution [here](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html).